# Zoom function in QT Designer with styleSheet

Tags: python, pyqt5, hover, zooming, qt-designer

I would like to have something like a zoom on a label in QT Designer, when the mouse hovers over it.
Like this:

```
QLabel
{
    transition: transform .2s;
}

QLabel:hover
{
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Is this even possible? The "code" above doesn't work in the styleSheet.
I can easily change the color by using the pseudo state "hover", but that's not what I need.

edit:
I solved the problem as you can see below, but if anyone knows a better solution, let me know.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):

# override the two methods
def enterEvent(self, QEvent):
    self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect( something bigger )

def leaveEvent(self, QEvent):
    self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRext( original size )
```

I found this for C++: [solution in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729040/how-to-create-qt-label-hover-effect)

Comment: As far as I know, unlike CSS, QSS does not support animations. You have to implement this functionality by yourself.

Comment: @user6528273 Yes, I overrode two methods of the QLabel class now and it's not a nice transition, but it works.

Comment: Why don't you try an [animation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html)?

Comment: @user6528273 I will definitely check this out! Thanks. I didn't know this exists.